# Overload a member methods for both intance and class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

I'm working on a python class which has a valid meaning for the index operator (`[]` or `__getitem__()` if you would prefer) at both the class and instance level. Specifically indexing strings is valid.  As such I would like to implement a dictionary interface for both levels.  The `__class_getitem__()` method solves this problem for the `[]` operator; However, I will still need other methods such as `keys()`, `__contains__()`, `__len__()` etc to behave differently if you for example call `cls.keys()` vs `cls().keys()`.

I'm fairly sure this can be done by using some combination of `__getattr__()` / `__getattribute__()` overloads and some tricky closure shenanigans. However, I would strongly like avoid doing so if at all reasonible for the following reasons:

- doings so is terribly clunky
- its confusing to non-expert coders
- hard to see and parse to the point of potentially blindsiding expert coders
- Tools like PyCharm's code completion system can't see that kind of stuff.

I suspect that the best answer will probably involve using a metaclass which I'm a bit resigned to but hope there is a clever way to avoid maybe through argument type detection and a decorator or something. (a subclass of `classmethod` which has a `instancemethod` attribute which gets called in the case of `not isinstance(cls, type)` maybe?)

Comment: `"its confusing to non-expert coders"` so is having the same method behave totally different if called on an instance or on the class. Can you justify this behavior?

Comment: `__class_getitem__` is intended for implementing generic types, not for type-level maps. Why do you need the other methods to work on a *class*?

Comment: class is an object type that represents environments. ```Environment[str]``` is a sensible request to ask for an object representing a given environment and ```Instance[str]``` has meaning for other reasons.  It would be nice to have the ```Environment``` type to implement the ```Dict``` interface itself so as to be able to query things like the full set registered env names + aliases and iterate over environments in a standardized manor.

Comment: You would need to implement the methods on the metaclass.